# choosing page size

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, grids, book, measurement

i'm designing a book for a poem, it will consist of roughly a line per page (anywhwere from 5-20 words) as well as a few images (1-4) per page. From reading JMB's "Raster systeme" he advises using the DIN system (A4,3,2 etc.) as it would be much more straightforward/less wasteful for all stages of printing/publishing etc. But i'm aware this book is 40 years old so i'm not sure if this still applies to the same degree . . So to clarify my questions are, am i much better off sticking to the DIN system?; and if not, does anyone know any comprehensive guidelines/books/rules for choosing page dimensions outside of that system?

Comment: Most books nowadays are not DIN sizes (if they ever were, which I think is doubtful). You can choose any size you want. The most important thing is that the size supports the contents and doesn’t work against it. Paper comes in standard sizes (as do printing machines), but impositioning software does a very good job these days of minimising waste, so unless your printer tells you that your chosen size is very wasteful, I wouldn’t worry too much about that. Just choose a size you think will work for your content and check with the printer that they’re happy with it.

Comment: Much will depend on the publisher/printer, even what country you are in.  Ask your printer.